# How to get iPhone crash log from customers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

Does anyone knows how to get crash logs from customers? Instead of manually asking them to sync and go to this directory and this directory and send it.

Is there any automatic way to do send a crash report to our server?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can perform your own crash-logging with [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). Typically, you write the crash log to a file and then send it to a server the next time the app starts.

In order to prevent an infinite crash-reporting loop (there was one in an early version), you want to do things in a specific order:

1. Read the file to memory and delete it. (Hopefully this won't crash.)
2. Parse the crash report and send it to the server. (If it crashes now, the file has been deleted, so it shouldn't happen again.)
3. Finally, enable crash reporting (so if it crashes in steps 1 or 2, the crash *isn't* logged).

In any case, you should have a "Oops, it crashed! Do you want to send a crash report?" dialog. I think automatic crash-logging is permitted by the default EULA, but it doesn't hurt to be nice to your users.

If you're worried about losing reports forever if the user says "no", instead of deleting the report, you can do logrotate-style style renaming (i.e. rename report8 to report9, rename report7 to report8, ..., rename report to report0). Then have a "send last N crash reports" button (either set N=10 or count the number of reports), so even if they've accidentally disabled it (or they had no internet at the time), they can still send the report.

Comment: Hi, would you comment my similar question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233388/ios-crash-log-catch-debug-info-catch-and-send-via-email-to-the-dev-team/8242215#8242215

Answer (score 13):

**iOS 5 and later**
Tapping Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage will allow you to choose between Automatically Send and Don't Send.

**iOS 4 and earlier**
By default, opting in is a one-time decision. If you'd like to change your decision, you can reset warnings for your iOS 4 or earlier device so that you will be asked again.

How to reset warnings within iTunes
Connect your iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch to your PC or Mac.
Wait until your device has appeared on the left side of the iTunes window under Devices.
Right-click (Mac or PC) or Control-click (Mac) the icon for your device.
From the shortcut menu, choose Reset Warnings:

The next time you sync after resetting warnings, you should see:

To disagree and stop sending Apple diagnostic and usage information, click No Thanks.

If you don't see the window above
Disconnect your device from your computer.
Open an application on your device.
Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the red slider appears, and then press and hold the Home button until the application quits. If you're using iOS 2.x or earlier, press and hold the Home button until the application quits.
Connect your device and sync it with iTunes.
The option to agree or disagree to diagnostics collection should appear again.

Chearz;)

reference:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4305

Comment: @henrikhodne if you have ever visited apple developer portal. There are crash logs. Always go confirm before you point out.

Comment: @The Saad The crash log list in ADC is buggy at best. Between a few different apps I've never seen a crash log appear, even for phones with this setting enabled. So while this may work for some apps, this has never worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In iTunes, with their device tethered, if the user control-clicks on the name for their device, they will be able to select "Reset Warnings".  Afterwards, a dialog box will pop up when the user next Syncs their device asking if it's OK to send data to Apple.  If they click OK, then iTunes will upload all the crash logs from their device to Apple's servers.

Afterwards, you should be able to find your crash logs in iTunes Connect, and download them yourself.  New crash logs will appear if your app still has problems and the user Syncs again, all automagically.

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about normal AppStore sales, Crash Reports are available through iTunes Connect.

Just go to "Manage Your Applications" -> "Your Application" -> And click "View Details" with the version currently active in the AppStore.

You will then get the details of your application, including the crash reports that are send in by your customers.