# How to get iPhone app users to submit crash reports?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone how to get crash log from customers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844482/iphone-how-to-get-crash-log-from-customers)

Some of my users are reporting crashes. What is the best way to explain to them how to send me their crash reports, so that they show up in the iTunes Connect list of crash reports? Do they get sent when users sync their phone with their computers? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They will show up in iTunes Connect automatically if the users have enabled that.

> When the user synchronizes their device using iTunes, crash reports
>   are copied to a directory on the user's computer. If the application
>   was distributed via the App Store and the user has chosen to submit
>   crash logs to Apple, the crash log will be uploaded and the developer
>   can download it via iTunes Connect.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html

Comment: +1 Specifically the [Acquiring Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SECTION3) section (more direct link).

Comment: But how to make visible methods names instead just numbers on the crash reports???

Comment: @Altaveron if you archived the build that the crash is against it should automatically symbolicate. However I would strongly recommend you use one of the services mentioned in this page, they are all much nicer to use than iTunes Connect. Crashlytics is another good choice- very easy to set up, very slick desktop client that alerts you instantly to live crashes.

Answer (score 17):

I've been using [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) to automatically get crash reports.  I like it better than iTunes because you get an email alert immediately after a crash.

Comment: +1 to Crittericism, its great!

Comment: I thought I can use Crittercism only on a development stage and will need to remove it before the real release. Just because iTunes Connect already has crash reports

Answer (score 14):

When the users sync with the computer they go to:

- Mac OS X :
  ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
- Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\\Application
  Data\Apple
  computer\Logs\CrashReporter/
- Windows Vista:
  C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple
  computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

The log file names start with application name and have the extension “crash”. They are just plain text files and can be sent by e-mail in original or zipped form, or even copy-pasted into your e-mail program.

From: http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/ after a SIMPLE search on google for "iphone crash reports".

Comment: what you say is true, but it's not what the OP is asking.  @Jason - yes, the crash reports will show up in iTunes Connect after the users sync their devices with iTunes on their desktops.

Comment: ah i see. missed that bit. my appologies

Comment: This response is very helpful as in my experience the crash report may not actually show up in iTunes Connect. My user who contacted me about a crash told me they did sync and send a report yet I still see "Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown" in iTunes Connect. Maybe if there's only one crash report Apple doesn't show it.

Comment: Note: your link is dead now, so thanks for quoting it.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) and get crash reports without asking the users.
Disclaimer: I am a co-founder at BugSense

Comment: Your link is broken, you need to remove the extra characters at the end. BTW cool looking software, will be checking it out in further detail.

Comment: @PanosJee what about data privacy? In germany we need to notify the user that we are about to send data and we do need an opt in to be allowed to send the data. Does bugsense support this native or do we have to implement it on our own?

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes, with their device tethered, if the user control-clicks on the name for their device, they will be able to select "Reset Warnings". Afterwards, a dialog box will pop up when the user next Syncs their device asking if it's OK to send data to Apple. If they click OK, then iTunes will upload all the crash logs from their device to Apple's servers.

Afterwards, you should be able to find your crash logs in iTunes Connect, and download them yourself. New crash logs will appear if your app still has problems and the user Syncs again, all automagically.