# how to send crash file from iphone device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to implement functionality such as after the application is distributed, if application get crashed on the device and user start it again then application should ask the user to send the crash report at predefined email address.

I want to know that how can I get the crash log when application get crashed ? I want to attach crash file in mail and if user wish to send that report, he/she can send it to the already defined email address.

How can I know at which point application get crashed ?

I searched on google but could not understand the approach.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got crash manager library from [here](https://github.com/kstenerud/Crash-Manager).

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, open Organizer. Then select the device with which the crash occurred. Under that, select **Device Logs**. If u want to open that file, do Right click on that, and reveal in finder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded the app to iTunes store, then log into iTunes connect and navigate to your application in "Manage your applications" and then to "View details" and then under "Links" you will see "Crash Reports". Apple gathers these crash reports from the users' devices and sends it to you on your iTunes connect portal. Check out the FAQ of iTunes connect portal about Application crash logs.

Comment: Programmatically, I don't think that would be possible. But there is no limit to what ios can do right. Check this previous answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325837/how-to-get-iphone-app-users-to-submit-crash-reports