# iPhone - detecting crashes, prompting user to send crash log

Tags: iphone, reporting-services, crash, crash-reports

Are there any libraries out there that would allow end users to send crash reports to developers?

For example, a user is using my app. It crashes. On boot up, a library loads before everything else and notices there is a crash report and prompts the user to send the crash log to me.

Is this possible? I think the Facebook app does something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: plz see my post here


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844482/iphone-how-to-get-crash-log-from-customers/10333308#10333308

Answer (score 8):

You actually have access to crash logs in [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com). Log in, go to Manage your Applications, pick an app, "View Details", and you should see a "Crash Reports" link to the right of the details pane.

That said, Apple only refreshes these daily, and will only give you access to reports of the most common crashes. If you want finer control, or need the user to submit reports directly, try [plcrashreporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). You could ask the user for a submission this way, or just go ahead and automatically send all reports to your server. From the plcrashreporter site:

> Introduction
>
> Plausile CrashReporter implements
>   in-process crash reporting on the
>   iPhone and Mac OS X. The following
>   features are supported:
>
> Implemented as an in-process signal
>   handler. Does not interfer with
>   debugging in gdb.. Handles both
>   uncaught Objective-C exceptions and
>   fatal signals (SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, etc).
>   Full thread state for all active
>   threads (backtraces, register dumps)
>   is provided. If your application
>   crashes, a crash report will be
>   written. When the application is next
>   run, you may check for a pending crash
>   report, and submit the report to your
>   own HTTP server, send an e-mail, or
>   even introspect the report locally.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sam! In iTunes Connect, are those user-crash logs that Apple uploads to iTunes connect automatically?

Comment: yep, that's correct. Apple stores these on the iPhone and syncs them with iTunes; if the user has opted in to crash log reporting, Apple populates your iTunes Connect with these, and refreshes the list daily. They don't give you every crash report, though. The plcrashreporter will get you a bit more control, for the cost of implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is [HopToad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/ios-notifier) - they host the site that will accept the crash reports and notify you.

Comment: Looks cool as well. It kind of sucks that even with the highest paid plan you can only have 64 users using it. Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: The 'users' are people who can create projects, not people using your app. I've used it on a few projects and find it useful (I've no connection to the company)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that we have been using at my company is Crittercism - http://www.crittercism.com/. They have been very responsive to feature requests and have really helped us prioritize which issues to address.

Their SDK also has the functionality I set out to look for so long ago! :)

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 5 and later**
Tapping Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage will allow you to choose between Automatically Send and Don't Send.

**iOS 4 and earlier**
By default, opting in is a one-time decision. If you'd like to change your decision, you can reset warnings for your iOS 4 or earlier device so that you will be asked again.

How to reset warnings within iTunes
Connect your iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch to your PC or Mac.
Wait until your device has appeared on the left side of the iTunes window under Devices.
Right-click (Mac or PC) or Control-click (Mac) the icon for your device.
From the shortcut menu, choose Reset Warnings:

The next time you sync after resetting warnings, you should see:

To disagree and stop sending Apple diagnostic and usage information, click No Thanks.

If you don't see the window above
Disconnect your device from your computer.
Open an application on your device.
Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the red slider appears, and then press and hold the Home button until the application quits. If you're using iOS 2.x or earlier, press and hold the Home button until the application quits.
Connect your device and sync it with iTunes.
The option to agree or disagree to diagnostics collection should appear again.

Chearz;)