# Simple application crashes

Tags: ios, crash

I have developed a simple app that calculates the risk of developing type 2 diabetes. The app runs fine from xcode on my iPhone 3Gs. I archived the app in a `.ipa` file and I have uploaded the app to my [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com) account. I have installed the app on my iPhone with the standard [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com) procedure: clicking the install link in the email from [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com).

When I run the app, I see the launch image for a few seconds and then it goes away. The console of my iPhone in xcode displays what is going wrong, but I do not know what this means:

```
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0xa6a]) Conflict with job: UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0x291b] over Mach service: com.reinvdo.diabete
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0xa6a]) Conflict with job: UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0x291b] over Mach service: com.reinvdo.diabete.UIKit.migserver
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[4255] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[4255] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/64A83260-5918-4109-A861-A3399D825654 [69] (sandbox)
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0x291b]) The following job tried to hijack the service "com.reinvdo.diabete" from this job: UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0xa6a]
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0xa6a][4255] <Notice>: Couldn't register com.reinvdo.diabete with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
Jan  8 20:00:42 unknown UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0xa6a][4255] <Notice>: This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.
Jan  8 20:00:43 unknown ReportCrash[4256] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process diabete[4255]
Jan  8 20:00:43 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.reinvdo.diabete[0xa6a]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Jan  8 20:00:43 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'diabete' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Jan  8 20:00:43 unknown ReportCrash[4256] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/diabete_2012-01-08-200042_reins-iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Can anybody shine a light on this error?

Comment: Check the saved crash report using the Xcode organizer or the iPhone Configuration Utility.

Comment: There is nothing in the console log that can help to answer - you need to post crash log

Comment: Yeah - as others have mentioned - this isn't the problem with the application on your phone.  This is the problem with the debug version (and this can happen easily during the development process).  You need to crash log from your device - and you can read here to get it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844482/iphone-how-to-get-crash-log-from-customers

Comment: hi, i risolved the problem: it seemed that on my iphone a process of a previous run of the application was still active on the iphone... i booted the phone and now it works perferctly.
thank very much all for your answers.
reinier

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone, a process of a previous run of the application was still active.  To fix the issue, all that is necessary is a reboot.