# Send app crash logs/regular app logs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, crash-reports

I want to implement "Report a problem" button in my app, which sends me the logs of the user's app as a text file (by email), so I can see what is the problem.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question. Just to leave a *boomark* here.

Comment: try at least searching same question... Anyway check this out http://www.ondemandworld.com/how-to-find-crash-logs/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844482/iphone-how-to-get-crash-log-from-customers for crash reports

Answer (score 2):

I have used [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/) to capture and retrieve crash logs from customers. It takes a bit of time, but once you get it set up, it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

[Crashlytics](http://www.Crashlytics.com) is definitely the way to go with crash logs. It is by far the easiest to implement and provides excellent information for solving problems as well as allows remote logging. It also means you will get the crash logs even without your users emailing them to you.

I'd still include a report a problem button that simply allows the user to email you if they have a problem specifically, but generally they won't for crashes.